# How can i give all images same size in magento 1.9 product listing page?

Tags: magento-1.9

Images in my product page are of different sizes. Some of them go long vertical. How can i make them all to same sizes ?

Comment: If you want to do this by CSS only, use `max-width` and `max-height` on `.product-image > img` class. Otherwise resize images by Magento library functions (by managing ratio)

Answer (score 1):

**Open your CSS file and add the following code.**

```
.product-image > img {
    width: 100px !important; height: auto !important;
}
```

width based on your desired size.

Comment: Thank you. But that just made all images smaller with the same dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Upload all images in the same ratio. Otherwise you will always have either images with long height or with big horizontal margin, dependent on your CSS.

Magento only resizes the images for thumbnails, it does not cut off anything.

Answer (score 1):

In catalog/product/list.phtml of your theme

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```

Replace the above code with

```
$height = Image height;
$width = Image width;
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(true)->resize($width, $height); ?>" width="<?php echo $width;?>" height="<?php echo $height;?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```